# Printing data with type unknown at compile time - can I do it without switch(name_of_type)?

Tags: c++, reflection, render-to-string

Suppose I need to implemenet a function with the following signature:

```
void print_elements(void* buffer, const std::string& element_type_name, size_t len, std::ostream& os);
```

Which is supposed to print/stream the `len` elements of `buffer` to output stream `os`. If I had the type at compile time then obviously I would just have

```
for(const auto& e : buffer) { os << e << " "; }
```

but I get the buffers from elsewhere, with only a string indicating their type.

Obviously I can't do

```
const size_t element_size = size_by_type_name(element_type_name);
for(it = buffer; it < (buffer + len * element_size); it++) {
    auto& stream_op_wrapper = get_stream_op_wrapper_for(os, element_type_name);
    stream_op(os, *it);
}
```

in C++. What do I do instead? I know C++ doesn't have reflection, but can I do better than looking up each time in a table of types? Or using static maps of string-to-`type_info`s ?

**Notes:**

- I can ask for additional meta-data.
- I can change signatures
- I can't get any additional information at compile time.

Comment: The best solution is to stop using untyped pointers (e.g. `void*`). You can replace it with templates, or if you have an "array" use e.g. `std::array` or `std::vector` instead (possibly in combination with templates).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I forgot to mention I don't control that. (And I could put the data in a vector but it'll still just be a vector of some arbitrary type, e.g. char).

Comment: If you can't change the function signature, then there's really nothing you could do, you have to use a set if `if` statements for the `element_type_name` and `reinterpret_cast` for the pointer. You could put the actual printing loop in a separate templated function that you call from this `print_elements` function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I was afraid you were going to say that. Maybe there are libraries which do that?

Comment: The list of possible type is limited and known ?

Comment: @Jarod42: Sort of. That is 1: It's negotiable.... this isn't some general-purpose library 2. These are not serialized classes; it's mostly basic types (uint8_t, int32_t, etc. etc.) but they can be also be bit fields (which should be printed appropriately and not just as multi-bit numbers), or variable-length sequences of characters (maybe even UTF-8 rather than ASCII).